# What flags must I give to gcc to perform auto-paralelization with autopar or graphite?

Tags: compilation, compiler-optimization

What flags must I give when compiling with GCC for it to perform autoparallelization? Are there separate flags for using autopar and graphite? I am aware that for doing no optimaztions is -O0 but what about automatic parallelization specifically and not general optimizations (pre-calculated results etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) `-floop-interchange -floop-strip-mine -floop-block` are the ones that use Graphite; Autopar gets enabled via `-floop-parallelize-all -ftree-parallelize-loops=X`, where `X` is the maximum amount of threads to be spawned when making a loop parallel (accoding to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/AutoParInGCC), both are needed).

All of these not enabled yet automatically at `-O3` (which you want to pass anyhow, as it enables other important optimizations).

Comment: Just a note: `-floop-strip-mine` and `-floop-block` do _not_ parallelize loops.